# Inject service in service in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm unable to inject a (global) service into another service.

boot.ts

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {GlobalService} from './common/global.service';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    GlobalService,
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS
]);
```

global.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalService {
    api_url: string = 'hello';
}
```

api.service.ts

```
import {Injectable, Inject} from 'angular2/core';
import {GlobalService} from '../common/global.service';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
    //constructor(@Inject(GlobalService) globalService: GlobalService) { // doesnt work
    //constructor(@Inject(GlobalService) public globalService: GlobalService) { // doesnt work
    constructor(public globalService: GlobalService) { // doesnt work
        console.log(globalService); // undefined
        console.log(this.globalService); // undefined
    }

}
```

It works fine when injecting GlobalService into an Component.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How is ApiService instantiated? Manually, by Angular (where), by `injector.get()`?

Comment: ApiService is a parent class from PageService and ProductService

Comment: How can I know know what `PageService` or `ProductService` is. ApiService needs to be instantiated somewhere. Is it injected somewhere? Did you add it to `providers` somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add ApiService to bootstrap as well

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ApiService,
    GlobalService,
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS
]);
```

Comment: Tried that with no success, still getting "undefined"

Comment: You didn't answer yet answer my questions in the comment to your question.